# Can a Class be Self-Referential?

Tags: c#, class

I know this is sort of an odd thing, and I don't believe that I'm going to go this route because it seems ridiculous and because I have a better alternative, but...

Can a class be self-referential?  Can it contain an instance of itself?  It compiles (at least in MonoDevelop), but I have to imagine there's wide potential for issues.

The code in question is:

```
public class DamageVehicle
{
    public int DVehicleID {get; set;}
}

public class DamageTypeArray
{
    public int[] DTypeArray {get; set;}
}

public class DamagePackage
{
    DamageVehicle dv;
    DamageTypeArray dta;
    DamagePackage dp;
}
```

Are there definite (non-opinion-based) reasons why this won't work in C#?  Assuming at some level, dp = NULL, it won't iterate over itself forever, though it appears to have the potential to do so.  What other issues can stem from this usage?

Comment: It is possible for a class to contains itself. It is allowed and perfectly legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't *contain itself* itself, it holds a *reference to* itself.

Yes, there is nothing wrong with this. A reference is essentially just a pointer, and this is exactly how linked lists are implemented.

Comment: Oh duh - that's is incredibly obvious and I somehow missed it entirely!  Good grief - thank you! lol

Comment: I think in the context of this question that you should state that it could be a reference to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Not only it's possible, it's not rare for it to be used in practice, a good example is the [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) pattern:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```